# How to "GROUP BY" array column in Cratedb

Tags: sql, cratedb

For example I have the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
     items  array(string)
)

INSERT INTO test (items) VALUES (array['a', 'b']);
INSERT INTO test (items) VALUES (array['a'])
```

Is it possible to count number of items in the table? Something similar to ES terms aggregation.

I expected something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(\*), items 
FROM test 
GROUP BY items;
```

But this raises an error

> Cannot GROUP BY 'items': invalid data type 'string_array'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of CrateDB 1.0 this is not supported. See [this GH issue](https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/4956) and [this](https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/3394)